# Kendo Angular Tooltip Shadow

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

I am using Angular and the Kendo control suite.  In particular I'm wondering about tooltip styling.

I have successfully styled the tooltip how I want it with one minor exception that I can't figure out.  There seems to be a shadow on the tooltip but it's around the entire extents including the little triangle callout piece so it doesn't fit the actual representation.

[image: Tooltip Border Weirdness]

It's pretty faint, but you can see the light edge of the shadow below the triangle (the red arrow I added to highlight it).

Here is my style:

```
.tooltipStandard *{
  background: var(--adskBlue);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.tooltipStandard .k-callout{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--adskBlue);
}
```

and I'm just using it like this:

```
<div class="contentSections" style="flex: 1" kendoTooltip tooltipClass="tooltipStandard">
```

Ideally I would like to have the shadow around just the blue portion of the tooltip but turning it off entirely would be fine too.

I tried to use the Chrome console to look at the styles but since it's a tooltip it won't stay open long enough for me to go to the inspection panel and select it.  It also doesn't show up when I force hover state from the developer console.  Is there any other way to inspect the element from the browser?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment below I was able to get the tooltip to stay up and therefore find what I needed to override.  Here is the much better output:

[image: Fixed Tooltip]

For anyone else having this issue, here are the styles I put into my code to make this update:

```
.k-animation-container-shown, .k-animation-container>.k-popup{
  box-shadow: none;
}

.k-tooltip-wrapper .k-tooltip{
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tooltipStandard .k-callout{
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}
```

The bottom style places the shadow onto the triangle and unfortunately it goes over the rectangle just a hair but you'd have to look pretty hard to see that so I'm not super concerned about that.  You could also just remove the triangle shadow.  If anyone has a good solution to 'clip' the triangle shadow on the top only that would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe you can add a stackblitz? It is working fine for me. You can use the the `showOn="click"` then click on the element to show the tooltip and inspect.

Comment: Awesome, the showOn attribute was what I needed, didn't know that was there.  After doing that I was able to determine where the classes were that I needed to override.  I'll update the question with the new code but if you want to make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer based on the comment by @yazantahhan above.

I just needed to find the right styles to apply.  Thanks to the comment I was able to set the tooltip to show on click using the `showOn` property.  To do so I changed this:

```
<div class="contentSections" style="flex: 1" kendoTooltip tooltipClass="tooltipStandard">
```

to this:

```
<div class="contentSections" style="flex: 1" kendoTooltip tooltipClass="tooltipStandard" showOn="click">
```

That allowed me to click the element and the tooltip stayed up and I could inspect it in the developer console.

Once I found that out I found the right styles pretty quickly.  Here are the css overrides I put into my style sheet to make it work:

```
.k-animation-container-shown, .k-animation-container>.k-popup{
  box-shadow: none;
}

.k-tooltip-wrapper .k-tooltip{
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tooltipStandard .k-callout{
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Fixed]